# Three.js, materials are black when rendering-to-texture then rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js, render-to-texture

http://jsfiddle.net/WNvDu/4/
That's just when it's rendering the scene.

http://jsfiddle.net/WNvDu/3/
Uncomment the render to texture line at the bottom, and I get this. The 3 objects are all black.

```
renderer.render( sceneToMask, camera, maskTexture, true );

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

The render to texture scene has two objects in it, the ones to the outside but not the donut in the middle.  I'm trying to make a mask of the two outter objects in the scene. You can see the render-to-texture displayed on the terrain when both renders are called in the render loop.

edit: If I do a new Three.Mesh() instead of .clone() it "works". http://jsfiddle.net/jK7JC/ But it doesn't really work because this isn't a solution, it's a poor hack.
There must be a way to cleanly make masks.

edit:
I've tried many things since posting this. I tried using two separate renderers. I've tried cloning objects. (like the above) Most things just fail outright. Other things work, but wouldn't work in production.
I need a way to render a stencil buffer or something, that's selective above what objects to render in the stencil or not.
I can't even get a basic stencil buffer to render, though.. I tried looking at MaskPass.js and I still can't figure it out.